# How to use vbApplicationModal with button and icon values in MsgBox

Tags: vbscript

I'm working on a personal project in VBScript, and I want to use the `vbApplicationModal` constant, whereby clicking out of the window will cause it to flash, like an error message would. Problem is, I have no idea where to put it in the MsgBox. I have:

```
X=MsgBox("Your details from this computer are being harvested using an altered malicious build of IBM Watson.", 0+48+4096, "IBM Watson")
```

However, I do not know where to put `vbApplicationModal`, or the alternative value (0). As you can see, I already used the values for icons and buttons rather than their vb codes (0 means there is only 'OK', 48 means there is a yellow triangular ***!***, 4096 means the window is always on top of other windows) because it is shorter. Do I have to use the value as well, or can I mix vb values and codes?

Comment: The value of the constant `vbApplicationModal` is 0, meaning it applies automatically. Expressly using the value is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this **[MsgBox Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/139z2azd(v=vs.90).aspx)**

You can mix value as well described in the link above

For example :

```
X=MsgBox("Your details from this computer are being harvested using an altered malicious build of IBM Watson.",vbExclamation+vbSystemModal+vbYesNo, "IBM Watson")

X=MsgBox("Your details from this computer are being harvested using an altered malicious build of IBM Watson.",vbCritical+vbSystemModal+vbYesNo, "IBM Watson")
```

***EDIT : Another example :***

```
Sample = msgBox("Option codes 0+64." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "This is an information situation with OK only",0+64, "Information.")
    Select Case Sample
        Case 1
            wScript.Echo "You acknowledged."
    End Select

Sample = msgBox("Option codes 1+48." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "This is a warning situation with OK and Cancel",1+48, "WARNING!")
    Select Case Sample
        Case 1
            wScript.Echo "You chose OK."
        Case 2
            wScript.Echo "You chose Cancel."
    End Select

Sample = msgBox("Option codes 2+16." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "This is a critical situation with Abort, Retry, and Ignore",2+16, "CRITICAL!")
    Select Case Sample
        Case 3
            wScript.Echo "You chose Abort."
        Case 4
            wScript.Echo "You chose Retry."
    Case 5
        wScript.Echo "You chose Ignore."
    End Select

Sample = msgBox("Option codes 0+16." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "This is a critical error situation with OK only",0+16, "CRITICAL ERROR!")
    Select Case Sample
        Case 1
            wScript.Echo "You acknowledged."
    End Select

Sample = msgBox("Option codes 3+32." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "This is a question situation with Yes, No, or Cancel",3+32, "Question?")
    Select Case Sample
        Case 6
            wScript.Echo "You said Yes."
        Case 7
            wScript.Echo "You said No."
        Case 2
            wScript.Echo "You clicked Cancel."
    End Select

Sample = msgBox("Option codes 4+32." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "This is a question situation with Yes or No only",4+32, "Question?")
    Select Case Sample
        Case 6
            wScript.Echo "You said Yes."
        Case 7
            wScript.Echo "You said No."
    End Select

Sample = msgBox("Option codes 5+16." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "This is a critical error situation with Retry or Cancel",5+16, "CRITICAL ERROR!")
    Select Case Sample
        Case 4
            wScript.Echo "You clicked Retry."
        Case 2
            wScript.Echo "You clicked Cancel."
    End Select
```